# Displacement Maps in cycles from Zbrush not rendering properly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying to render a mesh with a displacement map imported from Zbrush in Blender Cycles.

The sculpt and the map (as you can see in the image below) look fine, but the render in Cycles creates some weird 'artifacts' on some details... Actually, I've never managed to make displacement maps work correctly on Blender :( Tried to use the displacement modifier (which gives even weirder results) and the material nodes (rendered in the image).

The mesh itself is also imported from Zbrush (the lowest subdiv level).

[image]

Comment: Could be your UV map

Comment: Are you using a subsurf modifier?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/smooth-displaced-mesh and also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13385/how-to-replicate-this-effect-parts-of-material-more-reflective-than-others/13403#13403

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved!

I talked to a friend and he said that since the displacement map deforms the mesh according to the face normals (never knew that), I needed a normal map to smoothen the faces altogether before applying the displacement.

Material node setup as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but I will add my solution for anyone searching.

For myself this was caused by generating normal maps on subdivision lvl 1, then exporting the model at a higher subdivision level and then applying the maps in blender.

Whatever level you create the maps on, has to be the model you export to blender.

Comment: well, 5 years too late - I don't even work with 3d anymore - but this could definitely solve the problem too. I have already answered my own question back then, but I'm not sure about the results vs your method. life stuff ¯\_(ツ)_/¯